# Nginx & uWSGI: ImportError: No module named site

Tags: nginx, django, uwsgi

I'm receiving an error: `ImportError: No module named site` according to my uWSGI log.

**test_proj.ini:**

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /home/%n/app
module = %n.wsgi
home = /home/%n/app/venv
master = true
processes = 10
chmod-socket = 664
socket = /home/%n/uwsgi/socket
daemonize = /home/%n/uwsgi/log
pidfile = /home/%n/uwsgi/pid
```

**nginx:**

```
server {
        listen 8888;
        server_name 192.168.88.187;

        # Set up django static file serving
        location /static {
                alias /home/test_proj/app/static/;
        }

        # pass all non-static request to uWSGI
        location / {
                uwsgi_pass unix:///home/test_proj/uwsgi/socket;
                include uwsgi_params;
        }
}
```

**pip freeze:**

```
Django==1.7.1
django-braces==1.4.0
django-cors-headers==0.13
django-dynamic-settings==1.1.0
django-oauth-toolkit==0.7.2
django-uuidfield==0.5.0
djangorestframework==3.0.0
oauthlib==0.7.2
psycopg2==2.5.4
six==1.8.0
```

I also have uWSGI installed globally. Am I missing something in the `ini` file or is it because of my nginx settings? I've tried different combinations of the `ini` file.

I've also tried adding `no-site = true` inside the `ini` but I learned that it shouldn't be added to the `ini` file even though it removes the error and produces a different error.

I also followed this *[tutorial](https://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html)* but still no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: the HOME path is probably not correct.
Try adding a '/' at the end.
When you list that folder you should see bin/, include/, lib/, ...,mysite/ etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason why it wasn't working is because I installed `uwsgi` using the regular `pip` command. Since I have both Python 2 & 3 in the machine, I need to install `uwsgi` using `pip3`.

The command I ran: `pip3 install uwsgi`

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're getting this error is because the modules (site, os, etc) couldn't be found in the virtual environment specified in the home directive.  Using the right version of pip may have worked for you, but only because it fixes your virtualenv issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on venv, then run uwsgi using the full path of uwsgi where it resides inside the venv like `/usr/venv/bin/uwsgi`. Default uwsgi might be residing somewhere else.

Try `which uwsgi` to locate it.